# How do I handle a compromised AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Amazon Web Services notified me

> We've received a report that your instance(s):
>
> Instance Id: XXXX IP Address: XXXX
>
> has been making illegal intrusion attempts against remote hosts on the
>   Internet; check the information provided below by the abuse reporter.

I am running a Bitnami server on a single EC2 instance, which appears to have been compromised, and I'm trying to figure out the least disruptive way to fix the problem. Is the simplest solution to shut down the server, migrate my scripts and database to a new Bitnami instance, and change the administrator password?

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but Bitnami sent me an email late last year indicating that my server was running an older version of PHP vulnerable to [this security problem](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1823) and to remove this version by executing this command

```
sudo rm -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/php-cgi /opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/php-cgi.bin
```

I did this, but received the AWS notification within a week after I received this notification from Bitnami.

Comment: It is possible that your scripts are compromised as well. Best way is to create image from scratch and save snapshot for later use.

Comment: @Andrey Just to be sure I understand, by create a new image from scratch and save a snapshot, you mean add a fresh server instance, transfer the scripts/db to it, and create a backup of this newly populated instance in case I continue to have the problem, in which case I need to start combing my scripts for alien code?

Comment: I think you should avoid transferring anything from existing server. Especially executable files (including scripts). The problem is that you never know what piece exactly was compromised. You can try to find source of corruption, but you will never know was it the only one. So my idea is try not to reuse anything from that server.

Comment: Even your code could be compromised. I would not copy your code from the compromised server to the new one. You should be installing from your controlled sources (Repository, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kill it with fire.

Seriously, if the instance has been compromised in some way, you'll never be sure you haven't inadvertently transferred something with a nasty hidden payload even if you create a new instance and attempt to salvage anything from the old.

So kill it, then create and configure a new server from scratch. Bear in mind that the AWS ToS allows Amazon to kill the instance themselves and/or even terminate your account if they think you're not taking the problem seriously, so better to get it done yourself and tell them what you've done.

Comment: Bitnami creates regular backups, so I could backup to a point say 6 months before I got the abuse report (which came within a week of receiving the notification from Bitnami regarding the vulnerability). Do you think this would be sufficient? If not I can backup from a controlled source, but this will require me to reconfigure things.

Comment: @chris I'm confused because when I create a new Bitnami server, I see in my EC2 dashboard that this automatically creates a new EC2 instance. I assume this means that creating a new Bitnami server also creates a new EC2 instance in which to run the server?

Comment: Correct.  Birnami creates images (AMIs) that you use to launch your EC2 instance.  You then apply any needed config changes (i.e. database connection params, etc) and deploy your code.  Replace your old instance with the new one and you're back running a secure instance.

Comment: Oh, and just to be on the safe side I would create a new key, and probably update any AWS credentials you are using.